# How to group or concatenate different cells by changing values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv

I previously posted this question, but I have added a few new remarks - I have a large dataframe and I am trying to figure out how to concatenate cells with different values into one cell, given the following dataframe:
DF1: with Data and Name as headers

```
    Data,                          Name
    Address State1,                Name1
    Household = 1,                 Name1
    1012 Address 123 City,         Name1
    1013 Address Zip 12345,        Name1
    1012 Address 234 City,         Name1
    1013 Address Zip 23456,        Name1
    Address State2,                Name2
    Household = 2,                 Name2
    1012 Address 345 City,         Name2
    1013 Address Zip 34567,        Name2
    1012 Address 456 City,         Name2
    1013 Address Zip 45678,        Name2
    .......... dataframe repeats with different values for 10,000+ lines
```

1012 and 1013 is a different repeated sequence X amount of times. I can't just use a `groupby` function since the values in 1012 and 1013 cells are changing. I am trying to combine Address, Household, 1012..., 1013..., into one cell.
My desired output is:
DFOut:

```
    Data,                                                                                        Name
    Address State1   Household = 1   1012 Address 123 City        1013 Address Zip 12345,        Name1
    Address State1   Household = 1   1012 Address 234 City        1013 Address Zip 23456,        Name1
    Address State2   Household = 2   1012 Address 345 City        1013 Address Zip 34567,        Name2
    Address State2   Household = 2   1012 Address 456 City        1013 Address Zip 45678,        Name2
    ..... repeats for entire dataframe 10,000+ lines in DF1
```

Alternatively, cells in the `Data` column in DFOut can also be separated:

```
    Data,            Number,         Seq,                         Seq1,                          Name
    Address State1,  Household = 1,  1012 Address 123 City,       1013 Address Zip 12345,        Name1
    Address State1,  Household = 1,  1012 Address 234 City,       1013 Address Zip 23456,        Name1
    Address State2,  Household = 2,  1012 Address 345 City,       1013 Address Zip 34567,        Name2
    Address State2,  Household = 2,  1012 Address 456 City,       1013 Address Zip 45678,        Name2
    ..... repeats for entire dataframe 10,000+ lines in DF1
```

I attempted to use a few `for` loops to search the `Data` column based on values and then concatenating the different values into one column, but I loose the `Name` column for some reason after doing so. I am fairly new to Python and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a shot with use of str.match to locate the address text.

```
# generating mock data:
col_data = ['Address State1','Household = 1','1012 Address 123 City', 
        '1013 Address Zip 12345','1012 Address 234 City','1013 Address Zip 23456',
        'Address State2','Household = 2', '1012 Address 345 City',
        '1013 Address Zip 34567','1012 Address 456 City','1013 Address Zip 45678']
col_name = ['Name1','Name1','Name1','Name1','Name1','Name1','Name2' ,'Name2','Name2' ,'Name2' ,'Name2','Name2']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': col_data, 'Name':col_name})
# solution:
df.loc[df['Data'].str.match('Address'), 'Address'] = df['Data']
df.loc[df['Data'].str.match('Household'), 'Household'] = df['Data']
df.loc[df['Data'].str.match('1012 Address'), '1012 Address'] = df['Data']
df.loc[df['Data'].str.match('1013 Address'), '1013 Address'] = df['Data']

df['Address'] = df['Address'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['Household'] = df['Household'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['1012 Address'] = df['1012 Address'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['1013 Address'] = df['1013 Address']

df = df.dropna()
```

And the result is:

```
     Name         Address      Household           1012 Address              1013 Address  
3   Name1  Address State1  Household = 1  1012 Address 123 City    1013 Address Zip 12345  
5   Name1  Address State1  Household = 1  1012 Address 234 City    1013 Address Zip 23456     
9   Name2  Address State2  Household = 2  1012 Address 345 City    1013 Address Zip 34567     
11  Name2  Address State2  Household = 2  1012 Address 456 City    1013 Address Zip 45678
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there are always the same field in the same order you could do something like this using numpy reshape:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3']})
to_reshape = np.array(df['Data'])
reshaped = to_reshape.reshape((2, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=reshaped, columns=['1', '2', '3'])
print(df)

>>>     1   2   3
>>> 0  a1  a2  a3
>>> 1  b1  b2  b3
```

Then you could add name column. To know how many rows there is you could count unique names.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is only 10,000 rows, you could go with this loop:

```
DFOut = DF1.copy()
j = ''
k = ''
l = ''
row = 0
DFOut['Data'] = DFOut['Data,']
for i in DFOut['Data']:
    row +=1
    if 'Address State' in i:
        j = i
    elif 'Household' in i:
        k = i
    elif 'City' in i:
        l = i
    elif 'Zip' in i:
        DFOut.loc[row - 1, 'Data'] = f'{j} {k} {l} {i}'.replace(',', '')
DFOut = DFOut.loc[DFOut['Data'].str.contains('Zip'), ['Data', 'Name']]
DFOut = DFOut.rename({'Data' : 'Data,'}, axis=1)
DFOut
```

Output:

```
    Data,                                               Name
3   Address State1 Household = 1 1012 Address 123 ...   Name1
5   Address State1 Household = 1 1012 Address 234 ...   Name1
9   Address State2 Household = 2 1012 Address 345 ...   Name2
11  Address State2 Household = 2 1012 Address 456 ...   Name2
```